# some questions on exception safety and memory leaks

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, valgrind

If I have a class `A` and some body uses my code to create an object of `A`, then invokes `DoSth()` without `try-catch` around, will the memory leak? Do possibly lost and still reachable in valgrind's report indicate a memory leak? If not, how to avoid them? What's more, the constructor of `A` is not safe right? Have I got to use **smart pointers** to replace the raw pointer `Animal*` here? And there's a strategy called **"copy-and-swap"**, when to use it? Since the operator new may throw an exception, I'm little confused what to do when I want to dynamically allocate memory on the heap.

### Code

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const string& petname, int petage)
        :pet_(new Animal(petname, petage))
    {

    }

    ~A()
    {
        delete pet_;
    }

    void DoSth()
    {
        // do sth...
        throw;
    }

private:
    Animal* pet_;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    A a("Kitty", 3);
    a.DoSth();
    return 0;
}
```

### Valgrind Report

```
==2799== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2799==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2799==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2799==      possibly lost: 30 bytes in 1 blocks
==2799==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==2799==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: In this case: no because "a" is stack allocated and will be freed (calling its destructor) when exception will cause stack to unroll. You may have a leak if "a" is allocated on heap (or if you allocate memory in "DoSth()" but you don't free it because of the exception).

Comment: Why are you allocating the `Animal` object on the heap?

Comment: @ZacHowland It's just a demo for simulating the case that a class with pointer data members. And this class may throw exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Valgrind's report is showing a potential memory leak because you are letting the exception bubble up to the application level, which kills the application.  The resources are then freed.

However, some things to note:

1) If a function has the potential to throw an exception, you should handle that exception before it reaches the application level (at that level, the exception will kill your application - the idea of exceptions is to allow you to handle errors gracefully).

2) Why are you allocating `Animal` on the heap?  It could easily be allocated on the stack in this setup, in which case you would not have a potential leak showing in Valgrind, either.

If you are concerned about `new` throwing an exception (in practice, this typically only happens when you run out of memory to allocation ... so not very often), you would need to define your initialization in a separate function (even smart pointers would not avoid that issue for you), or have a try-catch block in the constructor, or don't put `Animal` on the heap.

Comment: Thanks! Zac Howland. After reading the chapter on exception safety in "Effective C++", I grow concerned about my code. And now, I feel a little better...